# Is RF Transformer Impedance Significantly Affected by Wire Size?

Tags: rf, transformer, impedance

I'm building a Softrock Ensemble III HF Receiver. The online instructions are pretty good, but have a few remnants from an earlier version that no longer apply. So, despite the discussion about the difference between #30 and #26 wire, when I saw that the two hanks of magnet wire were the same color I assumed they were the same size (in the RXTX kit they are different colors). When I wound T2 I used the #26 wire (which was a **very** tight fit) instead of the #30 wire. You can see the partial circuit diagram and the construction details for T2 [here](http://www.wb5rvz.org/ensemble_rx_iii/05_bpf) (scroll down to the Summary Build Notes, then click "Install BPF Input Components"). Do I need to remove T2 from the circuit board and rewind it with the smaller wire?

EDIT (adding details of the transformer, repeated from the linked page):

The transformer is 4 bifilar turns on a BN43-2402 ferrite transformer core. It's specified as 23.04µH for both the primary and the secondary. It's the RF input transformer; the primary connects directly to the antenna jack. The receiver covers the HF bands, 1-30 MHz.

Comment: Does the radio work?

Comment: @Andyaka - haven't gotten that far yet. Still have a dozen coils to wind (with the correct size wire, of course!). But that's a good point: I can wait and see.

Comment: For all those who have been on pins and needles waiting, yes, the radio works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a chart to show wire gauge variations.  You can see the resistance per distance column that using #26 opposed to #30 you are getting ~135 ohms per km versus ~340 ohms per km. If you got the proper number of turns, I wouldn't expect it to cause the radio to fail, but keep it in your notes as possible troubleshooting points.

[image]